# After H2-Upgrade

Tags: spring, h2

i did an upgrade of h2-database in my project and now it fails with this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException: Failed properties: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.h2.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Here is my spring-context.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>
```

And here my jdbc.properties where the spring-context loads the data to initialize my datasource:

```html
db.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
db.username=sa
db.password=

db.memurl=jdbc:h2:mem:test
```

All works fine with h2-version 1.4.179 but fails with 1.4.196. Used Spring Version is 4.2.8.

I don't get it why it fails... something has change in H2, but i don't know what... anybody an idea?

**--update--**

Here all dependencies from pom.xml (spring-version is 4.2.8) and this is a common project for all my test dependencies (packaging is pom), it is used by several projects. I use h2-database as in memory database only for testing:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Comment: Could you post your `pom.xml` or gradle build to show how you add the dependency?

Comment: I added the pom.xml to the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

or

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

if you are going to use h2 for test only

to the `h2` dependency

Comment: It cannot find the dependency measn the dependency exist on compile (you don't have compile errors i guess). Runtime means keep the dependency to be available for the app jar in runtime.

Comment: Yes, i didn't have any compile errors but i also use JPA, so i don't care about the used db. But why did the behavior changed with the version upgrade?! Because if i did a downgrade, all worked again... it was reproduceable.